# Missing exported symbols when building using MinGW linked with static library

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a simple c++ program with libcurl dependency:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

extern "C" int curlTest(void);

int curlTest(void) {
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to build it as a shared DLL library using MinGW on Windows. If compiled and linked with **dynamic** libcurl, everything goes well:

```
> g++ curlTest.cpp -c -o curlTestDynamic.o
> g++ curlTestDynamic.o -shared -o libCurlTestDynamic.dll -lcurl -lgdi32 -lws2_32
```

And If I list exported symbols of `libCurlTestDynamic.dll` with `dumpbin`, only the `curlTest` is shown in the output, as expected:

```
> dumpbin /exports libCurlTestDynamic.dll

    ...

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001450 curlTest

    ...
```

But if built with **static** libcurl, this `curlTest` symbol just got missing:

```
> g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB curlTest.cpp -c -o curlTestStatic.o
> g++ curlTestStatic.o -shared -o libCurlTestStatic.dll C:/path_to/libcurl.a -lgdi32 -lws2_32
> dumpbin /exports libCurlTestStatic.dll

    ...
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 000018A0 curl_easy_cleanup
          2    1 000018F0 curl_easy_duphandle
          ...
          (Lots of symbols like curl_* but no curlTest displayed)

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to decorate your own exports using `__declspec(dllexport)`.  I'm not sure why it works in one case and doesn't in the other, but adding the decoration should be foolproof.

Also take a look at the imports in libCurlTestStatic.dll.  Depending on how well libcurl.a was built, it could bring some unwanted imports.